# Traveler who aims to travel faster to reach better places

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember the title of a short story I read, and of course I don't even remember the author.

This is a story about a traveller, a member of some kind of organisation of travellers (almost mystical for some of its members?) who aim to travel always faster, as it seems that this speed makes them go to better places, better countries, some kind of higher existence. There is the legend of a place at the top of all this universe. It is not space travel, everything is happening on Earth, maybe some kind of multiverse even if it is not specifically explained that way from what I remember.

The character starts to feel that someone is trying to slow or stop him, so he decides himself to slow his travel to come back to our "level" and goes back to London (not sure about the city) to meet the man who allowed him into this organisation.

> At the end the character is in some kind of tree-city, and discovers that the person who was trying to stop him was in fact his contact in London, and that a girl he was suspecting was in fact trying to protect him like some kind of guardian angel. I think that at the end he dies stabbed.

(By the way French is my first language so I'm sorry if I made too many mistakes, and if my corrector allowed too many misspellings, as it is not configured for English.)

Comment: When did you read it? Do you know if it was new or old at that time?

Comment: I red it a few monthes (a year?) ago, I would say that it is recent, probably from the XXIst millenium, and absolutely not from 60's-70's.

Comment: Similar to this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54516/story-about-building-up-speed-leading-to-increased-quality-of-life/

Comment: YES that's it! Thanks a lot, I would never have guessed that the answer would have come so fast!